# Using Automapper to update an existing Entity with less Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, automapper, viewmodel

Im using EF5 and MVC. I am using Automapper to Mapp a Create Model to Edit Model. Because I need less properties in Edit than in Create.

Suppose this is my class I have binding with EF.

```html
 public partial class Users
        {
            public long User_id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "LastName cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

   [NotMapped] // Does not effect with your database
    [RegularExpression(@"^.{5,}$", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters required")]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password cannot be longer than 9 characters.")]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public virtual string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

In My DataBase table, the column `CreationDate` and `Password` are required

In My UserEditMode Model I do not need those properties.

```html
  public class UserEditView
        {public long User_id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "LastName cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 30 characters.")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

When I Update my table, I do a Mapper from UserEditView to User Model.

```html
  public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(UserEditViewModel model, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase image = null)
{
    var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.User_id == model.user.User_id);
      Mapper.Map<UserEditView, Users>(model.user, user);
     _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But, as I do not define `CreationDate` and `Passoword` for my Edit Model, there are setted to null in my User Model. So on `_db.SaveChanges();` gives me error on Update.

How can I mapp from Less Properties to Original Model an maintain those properties that are required to Map to My database?

thanks

It Works thanks!!!. But There is something missing...

I have defined as property

```html
 [NotMapped]
 [Compare("Password")]
 public virtual string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

As is NotMapped... when I Mapp

```
 Mapper.Map<UserEditView, Users>(model.user, user);
```

> user.ConfirmPassword is null.

It gives me an error on

```
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

I have to do

```
user.ConfirmPassword=user.Password before  _db.SaveChanges();
```

in order to work.

There is dirty doing something like this.

How can i Mapp when there is a [NotMapped] property?

thanks again

Comment: .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())

Comment: Can you check my answer and try in your code let me know if not helps if it work fine please mark it as answer .

Comment: Thanks!!! It Works using Ignore.... But sitll something do not work. I updated my question... I have another error... Thanks..

Comment: hi can you please paste both ur model and EF entity class please .

Comment: I updated my Users Entity with ConfirmPassword property. That is also my Model I use on Create View... and I define me EditUserModel with Users Properties I need. When I updated, is when error takes place. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use something like this when you configure your mapping .

```
 .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())

    For example 
     Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
    .Ignore(record => record.Field)
    .Ignore(record => record.AnotherField)
    .Ignore(record => record.Etc);
```